Closed form for the pdf of two IG variables (or its Mellin transform)
Context
I would like to find a closed form (not power series) for the pdf of the difference of two inverse gaussian variables. A direct computation of the convolution doesn't lead to any closed form (according to Mathematica).
I am also intersted in getting its Mellin transform !
Problem
I would like to derive an ode satisfied by a function defined as an integral. For $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \mu_1, \mu_2$ four real positive numbers, I define two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ as:
$$\forall x>0,~f_i(x) := x^{-3/2}\exp\left[-\frac{\lambda_i(x-\mu_i)^2}{2\mu_i^2x}\right].$$
Now, I define the the function $F$ as:
$$\forall z>0,~F(z) := \int_0^\infty f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx.$$
The value $F(0)$ can be derived using a bit of algebras and modified Bessel functions of second kind.  My question is the following, can we find closed form (special function?) for $F$ ?
What I've tried
I have tried to find a ODE satisfied by $F$ without sucess. I don't know other ways that would allow me to find the pdf or its Mellin transform.
Thank you!

I don't see why you should try to find an ODE of second order. Just differentiate and you will find that $f_1'(x) = \big(-\tfrac{\lambda_1}{2\mu_1^2} -\tfrac{3}{2x} + \tfrac{\lambda_1}{2x^2}\big)f_1(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. I could have made some computational mistake, though....

Thank you @HyperbolicPDEfriend for your comments. According to your formula, when I derive under the integral, I have to integrate the function $(x+z)^{-k}f_1(x+z)f_2(x)$ and I cannot get $F$ anymore... I defined $\varphi$ to avoid writing the composition of $f_1$ and $\cdot + z$.

Do you think that there is a closed ODE (just with $F$, without other integral) satisfied by $F$ ?

I see your problem. Certainly, no matter which RHS $g$ in the ODE $f_1'(x) = g(x, f_1(x))$ you get, it will always depend on $x$, because $f_1$ is not monotonic. I don't see a way yet to get a "nice" ODE. Substitution probably won't help either... What do you need the ODE for?

You are right, I have added the context in the post, it will be more clear. Thank you!

The only thing I can think about is to estimate $(x+z)^{-k} \leq x^{-k}$ and use some ODE comparison theorem. Also, you might want to try something like the convolution inequality?

Yes I would like to but I have to admit that I am absolutely not familiar with these analysis properties. I will try to improve myself. If you want to show me the first steps, would be very kind. Otherwise, no problem!

What I would just do is to estimate $F(z) \leq \sup_{z \in \mathbb{R}} f_1(z) \int^\infty_0 f_2(x)~\mathrm{d}x$. Or is this too rough?

Well, I more thought about a converging sequence of $F_n$ where for each $n$, where $F_n$ solves an "easy" ode

Unfortunately, such sequence does not come to mind :( I could only estimate this roughly
